# How to dynamically create tasks based on xcom value of previous task or airflow variable in airflow?

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-2.x, airflow-k8s

Using Airflow 2.2.3 with k8s executor.

I have a workflow like below,
Task2 generates a list and saves it to airflow variable "var1". the output varies on each execution. example: var1 = [1,2,3,4]
branch_operator takes the value from var1 and generates dynamic tasks 1-4.
Sometimes it doesn't take the latest values from var1 instead uses previous values when task2 executes within few seconds.

[image: airflow]

Tried adding `time.sleep(30)` in task2 works. because dag is refreshed based on configuration `AIRFLOW__SCHEDULER__MIN_FILE_PROCESS_INTERVAL` value is 30.

Is there any way to force refresh dag or any other better way to do this so that branch operator always takes the latest value and scheduled?

Comment: Can you provide some code for the solution you tried?

Comment: even you can do that, it is not the best practice. Airflow was created to tasks not for dynamic coding. you can handle all your cases you need inside a single task